# GAM Command to update Locations -> BuildingID

Tags: google-workspace, google-gsuite

My GAM is running, and I can pull users info, but I cant seem to find anywhere how to set the BuildingID value in Locations.

Ive tried below, but says buildingID is wrong.

gam user testguy@thisplace.com update BuildingID 12345

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the following command :

```
gam update user testguy@thisplace.com location type buildingid:12345 endlocation
```

With the above command I was able to update the buildingid of one user, you should expect an output similar to :

```
#gam update user test@domain.com location type buildingid:test123 endlocation
updating user test@domain.com...
```

You can review the following documentation for more information [gamcheatsheet](https://gamcheatsheet.com/GAM%20Cheat%20Sheet%20A3.pdf)